# How to change compiler version to build an Rcpp-based package?

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm authoring a package that uses an external `.so` library and a header file. I notice that it works with `g++-4.9` but not `g++5.0` or above after I compiled the demo code in pure C++ for testing. My system default is `g++ 5.4.0`.

I tried adding `CXX=g++-4.9` to `./configure` and `src/Makevars` but the compiler still turns out to be system default `g++`. I don't want to modify global configuration (e.g. in `~/.R/Makevars`) because it will influence other package builds.

Is there a local way to specify the compiler version Rcpp uses to compile `cpp` files when I build this package?

Comment: Tricky.  Is that a third-party / vendor-supplied library you do not have control over?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel yes, it is only a bunch of .so and a header.

Comment: Then the changes in compiler version (between 4 and 5, and IIRC also between 5 and 6) matter.  If you can get them to provide a C interface life becomes easier.

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: Set `CXX` for all varieties in `src/Makevars` this comes about because you might be using `CXX_STD = CXX11` so `CXX11` is used instead of `CXX`...

```
CXX=g++-4.9
CXX1X=g++-4.9
CXX11=g++-4.9
CXX14=g++-4.9
```

**Note:** This assumes you are only compiling C++ code.

Step 2: Test for gcc 4.9 in `configure.ac` with:

```
AC_PREREQ(2.61)

AC_INIT(your_package_name_here, m4_esyscmd_s([awk -e '/^Version:/ {print $2}' DESCRIPTION]))
AC_COPYRIGHT(Copyright (C) 2017 your name?)


## Determine Install Location of R
: ${R_HOME=$(R RHOME)}
if test -z "${R_HOME}"; then
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Could not determine R_HOME.])   
fi

## Setup RBin
RBIN="${R_HOME}/bin/R"
CXX=`"${RBIN}" CMD config CXX`
CPPFLAGS=`"${RBIN}" CMD config CPPFLAGS`
CXXFLAGS=`"${RBIN}" CMD config CXXFLAGS`

## We are using C++
AC_LANG(C++)
AC_REQUIRE_CPP

## Check the C++ compiler using the CXX value set
AC_PROG_CXX

## If the compiler is g++, then GXX is set so version information can be exaimed
if test "${GXX}" = yes; then
    AC_MSG_CHECKING([whether g++ version is sufficient])
    gxx_version=$(${CXX} -v 2>&1 | awk '/^.*g.. version/ {print $3}')
    case ${gxx_version} in
        4.9.*)
             AC_MSG_RESULT([(${gxx_version}) yes])
        ;;

 1.*|2.*|3.*|4.0.*|4.1.*|4.2.*|4.3.*|4.4.*|4.5.*|4.6.*|4.7.*|4.8.*|5.*|6.*|7.*)
             AC_MSG_RESULT([no])
             AC_MSG_WARN([Only g++ version 4.9.* be used to compile this package.])
             AC_MSG_ERROR([Please set the default compiler to gcc++-4.9.])   
    ;;
    esac
else
 AC_MSG_WARN([The package uses an external shared library that only compiles with gcc++-4.9])
 AC_MSG_ERROR([Please set the default compiler to gcc++-4.9.])   
fi

AC_OUTPUT
```

Comment: Yep. One can request `g++-$VER` but then the onus is on you to test for presence of `g++-$VER`.

Comment: I test the code put in `./configure` but it says `./configure: 1: ./configure: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")` when I build the package.

Comment: Forgot to add `AC_OUTPUT` at the end.